I have an endpoint in springboot which deletes and loads the cache.When it is called within fraction of s, cache is loading the double amount of data?
I have a SpringBoot application. I have an endpoint which deletes the cache and reloads the cache in my application for given table in given date.
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public boolean reloadCache(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestbody){
String table = requestbody.get("table");
String date = requestbody.get("date");
return reloadCacheService.reloadCache(table, date);
}

I have following code in ReloadCacheService:
public boolean reloadCache(String table, String date){
LocalDate localDate = Util.methodToConvertStringToLocalDate(date);
deleteCache(table, date);
loadCache(table, date);
return true;
}

So, whenever if I hitting the endpoint twice within fraction of seconds for same table and same date, I am getting the double the amount of original data in cache. This is happening because first deleteCache is happening at the same time and then loadCache is happening. If I hit the endpoint only one, then it is working as expected. What is the best way to handle this issue?
I am looking at a multi threading way or asynchronous way to handle this issue. I haven't made any fix because in production there is no chance that we are hitting the endpoint with same date and table within fraction of seconds. But, I want to know an efficient way to handle this.

It seems like you have a race condition. When two requests come in parallel, both are most likely going through same areas of code at same time, thus both are likely loading at same time. If cache is singleton, then it will have double the data. This is all very dependent on how you implemented your methods.
You will need add some handling for multithreading, most likely a simple lock will suffice.

The methods are synchronous and they don't have any multi threading.

Yes, but requests are processed in parallel by separate threads, and if your objects are singletons (which they are by default), then you get two threads working on your objects at the same time.
